# Binding JSON data to a html angularjs data table

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular

Im a newbie to angular, currently i have created a datatable using html and angular, can you guys help me on how to bind a JSON data into this table... my scripts are as follows

html script

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-4">
    <page-title [title]=pageTitle></page-title>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <data-table [dataTable]="dataTable" ></data-table>
  </div>
</div>
```

ts script

```
  export class UploadsComponent implements OnInit {

  pageTitle = '<i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i>Uploads';

  dataTable: DataTable;

  constructor() { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initDataTable();
  }

  initDataTable() {

    let startDateHeader = new DataTableHeader();
    startDateHeader.text = 'Start Date';
    startDateHeader.dataType = DataTableColumnDataType.DATE;

    let uploadtypeHeader = new DataTableHeader();
    uploadtypeHeader.text = 'Upload Type';

    let statusHeader = new DataTableHeader();
    statusHeader.text = 'Status';

    let modifiedDateHeader = new DataTableHeader();
    modifiedDateHeader.text = 'Modified Date';
    modifiedDateHeader.dataType = DataTableColumnDataType.DATE;

    let descriptionHeader = new DataTableHeader();
    descriptionHeader.text = 'Description';

    this.dataTable = new DataTable();
    this.dataTable.headers = [startDateHeader, uploadtypeHeader, statusHeader, modifiedDateHeader, descriptionHeader];

  }

}
```

and this is the output table i got

[image]

so can anyone give me some guidance on how to properly bind data to this table which comes in a JSON

Comment: any tip about this from any angular experts??

Comment: or else can anybody provide me a link to take some tips for this!!!

Comment: somebody please help!!

Comment: what kind of `<data-table>` are you using? Or is it a custom component? If so, please provide the code for that as well